# Spring MVC User retrieval strategy

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-security

I have a pretty common Spring Web MVC application using Hibernate. The user of the application are stored in a table called USER and there also username, password and a couple of other properties  are stored. Also I am using Spring security with jdbc-user-service in order to secure the application so that only user from this table can access is with their username / password.
Now my problem is that once logged on, I need to access this user object quite often, e.g. in order to get all orders from this user, the address of this user and so on. I know how to access the Principal object, which shares username with my User Object, but I am wondering which would be the best strategy to easily access my custom User object. There are a couple of strategies like putting it in the session, write a findUserByUsername() method and call it whenever needed (which would result in hitting the database quite a lot I think) but I am looking for a smarter way. Is it somehow possible to inject a User object? Or should I rather put it in the session? If so, how would be the best way to achieve this? How could I hook in after the Spring frameworks login event?
Any suggestions?
Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You could always scope a UserDetails bean to the session ([link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)).  This would, of course, be a stateful bean, so you would be free to store any information about your User entity that you need to and access it as long as the session is active.  One trip to the database.

*Note:* The User object (and any related objects) will be **detached** from the Hibernate Session.  Keep this in mind when either 'storing' the values within the bean or accessing them in later processing.